# what is the universal cover for $S_g$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Denote $S_g$ to be orientable, compact closed surface with genus $g$; especially, $g=1$, $S_1$ is just the torus, it has the universal cover $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I heard the universal cover for $S_2$ is upper half plane $\mathbb{H}^2=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|y>0\}$, how to prove this? And what is the universal cover for $S_g$ with $g>2$?

Comment: For $g\geq 2$ I believe the universal cover is the upper half plane. Recall that the universal cover of a Riemann surface is either the plane, the sphere, or hyperbolic space, and that for $g\geq 2$ the surface $M_g$ is a hyperbolic Riemann surface (with appropriate choice of complex structure).

Comment: $M_g$ is bad notation here; in this context it often means the moduli space of curves of genus $g$, which is very different. I would use $S_g$.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the notation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) Any manifold admit a universal cover and the dimension is the same ;
2) The only two simply connected surfaces are the plane and the sphere.

If you look at your compact surface of genus $2$ as a complex manifold, then there is the famous Uniformization Theorem which states that there are only 3 different simply connected complex manifold of dimension 1 : the plane, the sphere and the half-plane.

Comment: Thanks! Since I only learnt the stuff on universal cover recently, so I expect a proof of the fact mentioned in the question, now as you mentioned, maybe it is not so easy to see this fact.

Comment: The uniformization theorem is one way to prove this fact but it is not the only way. You can also exhibit explicitly, for every $g \ge 2$, a subgroup of the group of isometries of the upper half-plane with quotient a surface of genus $g$.

Comment: @Qianchu: May I ask how to construct this explicitly for a 3 hole torus?